# Как имплементировать метод characteristics() при реализации класса Collector?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Пытаюсь реализовать `Collector` *(Java 8, Stream API)*, создавая объект анонимного класса. Я застрял на имплементации метода `characteristics()`.

Вот, что о нём написано в javadoc:

> Returns a Set of Collector.Characteristics indicating the
> characteristics of this Collector. This set should be immutable.

Проблема в том, что всего в `Characteristics` есть три варианта того, что можно возвращать: `IDENTITY_FINISH`, `UNORDERED`, `IDENTITY_FINISH`. Но ни одно из этих свойств мне не нужно.

Сейчас я реализовал `Collector` вот так *(самое важно внизу)*:

```
Collector<UserMeal, List<UserMealWithExcess>, List<UserMealWithExcess>> mealsCollector =
                new Collector<UserMeal, List<UserMealWithExcess>, List<UserMealWithExcess>>() {
                    private Map<LocalDate, Integer> dateExcess = new HashMap<>();

                    @Override
                    public Supplier<List<UserMealWithExcess>> supplier() {
                        return ArrayList::new;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public BiConsumer<List<UserMealWithExcess>, UserMeal> accumulator() {
                        return (o, o2) -> {
                            o.add(new UserMealWithExcess(o2.getDateTime(), o2.getDescription(), o2.getCalories(), new Boolean[]{false}));
                            dateExcess.merge(LocalDate.from(o2.getDateTime()), o2.getCalories(), Integer::sum);
                        };
                    }

                    @Override
                    public BinaryOperator<List<UserMealWithExcess>> combiner() {
                        return (o, o2) -> {
                            o.addAll(o2);
                            return o;
                        };
                    }

                    @Override
                    public Function<List<UserMealWithExcess>, List<UserMealWithExcess>> finisher() {
                        return (o) -> {
                            o.forEach(x -> x.getExcess()[0] = (dateExcess.get(LocalDate.from(x.getDateTime())) > caloriesPerDay));
                            return o;
                        };
                    }

                    @Override
                    public Set<Characteristics> characteristics() {
                        return Collections.unmodifiableSet(EnumSet.of(Characteristics.UNORDERED));
                    }
                };
```

Насколько видно, сейчас `characteristics()` возвращает `Characteristics.UNORDERED`, т.е. этот маркер сообщает о том, что коллекция неупорядочена.

А можно мне вообще ничего не возвращать в этом методе? Есть ли какое-то дефолное свойство?

Потому что, если возвращать `null`, это вызовет `NullPointerException`.

Comment: Этот вопрос в данный момент включает несколько вопросов. Его следует переформулировать, чтобы он был сфокусирован только на одной проблеме.

Comment: Декомпиляцию функции `characteristics` уже смотрел?

Comment: @RomanC один у меня вопрос: как реализовать метод characteristics(), если мне не нужно возвращать CONCURRENT, UNORDERED или IDENTITY_FINISH. 
Но, видимо, кидать тревоги проще, чем ответить, да? Тем более, если ответ не знаешь.

Comment: @MikhailIonkin в первый раз слышу о таком честно говоря. Я начинающий в Java. Что вы имеете в виду?

Comment: Приведите пример кода в вопросе, нам непонятно, что вы вообще хотите сделать и получить на выходе.

Comment: @Komdosh постарался максимально подробно описать. Добавил пример кода.

Comment: можно Collections.emptySet(); вернуть

Comment: @Zhenyria компиляция JVM -- это преобразование Java-кода в оптимизированный байт-код. Декомпиляция -- это обратный процесс: получение исходного кода по байт-коду. В современных средах разработки, например, в Intellij Idea, можно кликнуть мышкой по функции и посмотреть её реализацию, даже если нет исходного кода. То есть вы можете посмотреть конкретную функцию класса Collection

Comment: @MikhailIonkin я понял о чём вы. characteristics(), это метод из интерфейса Comparator, он абстрактный и, соответственно, не имеет своей реализации.

Comment: @Zhenyria почти любая функция из стандартной Java имеет реализацию. Если она не реализована в этом классе, значит, раелизована в наследных.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ответом на вопрос является `return Collections.emptySet();`, но может кому-то будет интересно, что это и с чем его едят.

Дело в том, что метод `characteristics()` подсказывает приложению как обращаться с элементами при терминальной операции.

Возвращаемый `Set<Characteristics>` содержит дополнительную информацию для оптимизации. По большей части она нужна в многопоточных реализациях.

- `Collector.Characteristics.IDENTITY_FINISH` - Означает, что в терминальной операции будет возвращён единственный элемент, так что аккумулятор можно сразу скастовать к необходимому типу (`(R) finalAccum`). В противном случае вызывается дополнительные методы `collector.finisher().apply(finalAccum)`.
- `Collector.Characteristics.UNORDERED` - элементы имеют ассоциативность (`a*(b*c)==b*(a*c)`), но при этом может отсутствовать коммутативность (`a*b` не всегда равно `b*a`). В документации приводится пример комбинации двух списков `List`, для них ослаблена операция эквивалентности, предоплагается, что если эти два списка содержат одинаковый набор одинаковых элементов, то они равны, не смотря на то, что сами одинаковые элементы могут находятся в разных позициях этих списков.

  При исполнении этого кода

  ```
   A a2 = supplier.get();
   accumulator.accept(a2, t1);
   A a3 = supplier.get();
   accumulator.accept(a3, t2);
   R r2 = finisher.apply(combiner.apply(a2, a3));
  ```

  На последней строке сохраняется порядок комбинации коллекций `combiner.apply(a2, a3)`, что требует сохранения порядка выполнения операций.
- `Collector.Characteristics.CONCURRENT` - Аккумуляторы могут быть одновременно вызваны в нескольких потоках, при этом если коллектор не содержит характеристики `Collector.Characteristics.UNORDERED`, то многопоточная реализация может быть применена только к неупорядоченным (`unnordered`) коллекциям, например к `Set`.

Более подробная [информация по коллекторам](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collector.html).